# does STL has hashmap data structure?

Tags: c++, stl

I have used unsorted_map from TR1. 
I never know any data structure from STL is hashmap.
My coworker insists that STL has hashmap, which he cannot (or not willing )find for me.
Could anybody judge this argue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Standard C++98 does not have a hash map, but many implementation of the STL, like the original [SGI implementation](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/), do have a [hash_map](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/hash_map.html) class.

Comment: THANKS, i got it. That's why. :D

Answer (score 3):

The SGI STL (from which GCC's is based) does have a [`hash_map`](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/hash_map.html) implementation. This is not standard C++ however.

Comment: That is not _the_ STL; that's just _an_ STL.

Comment: From the page you linked to: This class is an SGI extension; it is not part of the C++ standard.

Comment: Point taken, fixed my answer. Thanks :)

Comment: @Nicol: actually the SGI one is *the* definitive STL - Stepanov and Lee used the name while working at HP, and SGI took it over. Dinkumware also use the name. The standard incorporates parts of it, with some changes. People who refer to certain parts of the C++ standard as "the STL" are creating needless confusion IMO, the standard does not and never has claimed that any part of it is called "the STL".

Comment: @Steve: But _everyone_ does that. At this point, "STL" now is synonymous with "C++ standard library." Language is defined by how it is used, not by who first created a term. So if everyone refers to the C++ standard library as "STL", then "STL" means the C++ standard library. At which point, the only confusion that is created happens when someone insists on the original usage of the term.

Comment: @Nicol: it is not true that everyone does that. It is also not true that STL is synonymous with "C++ standard library", since various people, when speaking of "the STL" do not intend to include iostreams or exceptions (which aren't templates) or headers like `<cstring>` which are part of the C++ standard library but their contents aren't new to C++. Technical people should be able to use technical terms precisely, which "everyone" you know fails to do. When "STL" is assessed to appear in an English dictionary, we can talk about common usage, until then it's a technical term :-)

Comment: I concede that when those people you know use "STL" to mean "some slightly ambiguous subset of the C++ standard libraries", it generally doesn't matter exactly what they mean, because they generally aren't saying anything substantial about it. They're just a recruitment weasel or manager ticking a box, or a programmer talking in very vague generalities about "containers and that sort of thing". But if you embark upon pedantry ("just an STL") I think you need to be working from a clear definition, not just an impression of vague usage.

Answer (score 2):

In C++0x, there's an `unordered_map` and `unordered_multimap`, that'll usually be implemented as hash maps.

If your compiler doesn't have them yet, you can use [`boost::tr1::unordered_map`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/doc/html/unordered.html).